# Change focus using keypress

Tags: python, python-3.x, urwid

I need to implement a feature with URWID, where if I press a key, say <kbd>c</kbd>, the focus should go down to the bottom most point in that page. Here, page is nothing but a `ListBox`. This 'ListBox' is too long to be operated using just <kbd>down</kbd> or <kbd>page down</kbd> keys (Think of this like a page, where it takes long time to go down to the bottom most point of the page, if it has many lines)

1) I could access the key pressed using 'keypress'. After accessing the key, how to change the focus?

I found 'focus_position' function inside 'keypress'. I'm having difficult time to use this function to change the focus to required position.

Reference: http://urwid.org/reference/widget.html

EDIT:

I tried following code. But it's not working.

```
if key is "c":
        position = self.focus_position
        self.focus_position = position + 10
```

EDIT 2:

```
def keypress(self, size, key):
    key = super(MyListBox, self).keypress(size, key)
    if key is "c":
        pos = self.focus_position
        if pos > 100:
           pos = 0
           self.focus_position = 0
        self.focus_position = pos + 5
```

Problem with above code is, this is not stable. It terminates the program after pressing the key "c" multiple times saying 'No widget at position xxx'.

Thoughts?

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, the items of the ListBox are bigger than the screen, and you want to "paginate" through them, moving the focus to the last element inside of the ListBox that's showing up in the screen -- is that it?

Comment: That's all. I want to move the focus to the last point or may be to the middle, i want to have the control over the focus.

Comment: any thoughts on how to implement it?, you can give me some hints and i'll work on them.

Comment: Hi! I've been wanting to try it out, but many things got in the way. It would be really helpful if you shared a small minimal example which demonstrated the problem you want to solve. I want to help you, but for that i'll have to write an example from scratch to test it out, and i haven't yet found the time to do it...

Comment: For setting the focus, have you tried this? http://urwid.org/manual/widgets.html#setting-the-focus

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyListBox(urwid.ListBox):
   def keypress(self, size, key):
     if key == 'u':
        self.set_focus(0)
        key = None
     elif key == 'd':
        self.set_focus(len(self.body) - 1)
        key = None
     return key
```

Above code is working properly. Thanks.